# Dynamically added items in LinearLayout margin

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-checkbox

I have code to add checkboxes from an Array to the LinearLayout.

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
for (int n = 0; n < listitems.size(); n++) {
  CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
  cb.setId(Integer.parseInt(listitems.get(n).get("cbid")));
  cb.setText(listitems.get(n).get("product"));
  cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
  my_layout.addView(cb);
}
```

how can i make sure that between each checkbox there is a margin of 2-3dp?
And that the background of the checkboxes has rounded edges?

This is my XML to set the boxes in

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#13ca8c"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
for (int n = 0; n < listitems.size(); n++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setId(Integer.parseInt(listitems.get(n).get("cbid")));
    cb.setText(listitems.get(n).get("product"));
    cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parms.leftMargin = 2;
    params.rightMargin = 2;
    params.topMargin = 2;
    params.bottomMargin = 2;
    my_layout.addView(cb,params);
}
```

And for rounded corners use a background image

Comment: i don't want to add a new layout i want to adjust it into my already  in XML defined layout.

Comment: @user3671459 you won't be adding a new layout you will just be setting the layout margins to your view